# Some font sizes are strangely big

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, fonts, lubuntu, size

On my Lubuntu (ubuntu based) VM I see different font sizes, it's very strange.

In some apps it looks normal, in others the fonts are extremely large. Even in some apps there are some huge variations of the font sizes between a section and another.

What can I do?

**Screenshots**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Guess: funny DPI settings, and/or fonts installed for several DPI settings, and or fonts from different sources (e.g. bitmap vs. fontconfig). Unfortunately, debugging font choice isn't easy. Have a look at `xdpyinfo`, `xlsfonts`, `xfontsel`, and `fc-*` for starters.